# Ways to speed up open_mfdataset in xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to open a large number of NetCDF files (340 GB, 7,000+ files) with the `open_mfdataset` function in xarray. However, when I try to read a sorted list of all of thse file names into `open_mfdataset`, it takes a very long time (~30 minutes) to finish. Maybe this is expect behavior given the size of what I'm trying to read, but it is my understanding that most of the computation time should happen after I process the Dataset how I want and then finally call `.compute()`

Should `open_mfdataset` be taking this long? Is there any way to speed it up? I know there is the "chunks" argument, but my understanding is that that is really only relevant if I'm doing parallel computing on a supercomputer...

Some sample code...

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from glob import glob

files = np.sort(glob('filepath/*.nc'))
print(len(files))
>>> 7479

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(files)
```

and here's what the dataset looks like if I load just one file...

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(files[0])

print(radar_data)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (bounds: 2, time: 1, x0: 301, y0: 301, z0: 30)
Coordinates:
  * time            (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-08-20T00:31:32
  * x0              (x0) float32 -150.0 -149.0 -148.0 ... 148.0 149.0 150.0
  * y0              (y0) float32 -150.0 -149.0 -148.0 ... 148.0 149.0 150.0
    lat0            (y0, x0) float32 18.32 18.32 18.32 ... 21.01 21.01 21.01
    lon0            (y0, x0) float32 120.8 120.8 120.8 ... 123.7 123.7 123.7
  * z0              (z0) float32 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 ... 13.5 14.0 14.5 15.0
Dimensions without coordinates: bounds
Data variables:
    data            (time, z0, y0, x0) float32 ...
```

Comment: Please share some example code, if possible reproducible

Comment: It's just one line of code, `df = xr.open_mfdataset(files)`, where `files` is a list of strings. No way to make it completely reproducible without uploading hundreds of gigs of data?

Comment: If you're reading 7k+ files sequentially, I wouldn't be surprised - but then again, are you? This is the kind of thing that's a bit clearer if you show some of your code.

Comment: did you set `parallel=True` or do you use any other form of concurrency / dask?

Comment: ok, I've added some relevant code and info to the post. I have not set the parallel flag to True or tried anything with chunking.

Comment: try `parallel=True` ... otherwise you can work with chunking - this lets you work with the full dataset before it's loaded to memory and is definitely not only for supercomputers. The data is only read when you finally execute `compute`, and depending on your workflow and chunking, can be much more efficient than loading everything beforehand.

Comment: Choosing a good number for chunking is a bit of a mystery to me and I find the documentation confusing. Given the dimensions of my data (in the original post), what numbers would you suggest?

Comment: It's not a straight forward thing, there're a lot of tradeoffs. I can't tell you numbers, but the performance will mostly depend on a) the chunking of your input files, b) the number of chunks and c) what the processing looks like. Try to see if the netcdfs are chunked in any way, remembering each worker process will read chunks individually. I'm assuming the fastest way will be a chunking scheme, that maps one file to one chunk

Answer (score 3):

I've also had trouble with this, and my solution has been to use multiprocessing, as the dask parallel=True seems to result in slower reading whenever I try it.

Having got your list of files, use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to read in each file using [xr_opendataset](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html), and then do some processing if you like.

Then call [xr.concat](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html) on your list of xarray results.

This has given me speed increases of 3x or 4x relative to using open_mfdataset

Comment: I had the same issue. open_mfdataset was too slow for me.I used python's joblib to parallelize the nc file reading, which was much faster.