# Performance improvement of xarray.open_mfdataset() to extract single grid point data from NetCDF files

Tags: python-xarray, netcdf4

I have downloaded daily wind data from the ERA5 database in NetCDF format from 1979-2020 (42-years). Hence, I have 15330 `.nc` files. I need to extract wind data for one single grid point, and need to make this process as quick as possible.

Since opening 15300 files, each of size 97MB using `xarray.mfdataset()` function is too slow, first I have combined the daily data into yearly data and stored in a folder. I used following command to do this:

```
for i in range (1979,2021):
    InputFileNames = 'path to daily files\ea_wind_' + str(i) + '*.nc'
    ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(InputFileNames,combine = 'nested', concat_dim="time", parallel=True)
    OutputFileName = 'path to yearly files\'+ str(i) + '.nc'
    ds.to_netcdf(OutputFileName)
```

Now I have 42-years of data in 42 files, each about 35GB in size. Now I want to extract data for a single grid point. I am using the code:

```
# Load Libraries
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from tictoc import tic, toc
import xarray as xr
import h5netcdf
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import glob, os

# Starting time counter
tic() 

# Input a single Lat, lon for extracting data near that grid point
lat = 8.0
lon = 303.0

# Input file location
# Wind
base_dir = 'Y:\\ERA5\\Yearly Data\\Wind\\'

glob_pattern = os.path.join(base_dir, '*.nc' )

print('Step 1: Opening multiple NetCDF files to read')
data = xr.open_mfdataset(glob_pattern, decode_times=True, chunks={'time': 1000},
                       engine='h5netcdf', data_vars='minimal', coords='minimal', compat='override', parallel=True)
                       

print('Step 2: extracting data for given grid point')
data_single = data.sel(latitude = lat, longitude = lon, method='nearest')

print('Step 3: Exporting into NetCDF file')
delayed_obj = data_single.to_netcdf("extract.nc", compute=False)

with ProgressBar():
    results = delayed_obj.compute()

# Showing total time taken
print('Time taken for data extraction: ')

toc()
```

It's taking over 4-hours to extract the data. I am not sure if I am using the xarray functions properly, and looking for any solution to make the data extraction quicker.

Appreciate any advise.

Comment: share all your files the same grid? In that case you can try to extract the point using iloc and the exact indices, that might be faster.

Comment: I believe the latitude and longitude are the same across all files. However, I couldn't find a way to identify which index correspond to the selected latitude and longitude value. Could you give me a example for xarray dataset?

Comment: Maybe Step 2 spends little time when compared to Step 3, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use the preprocess argument in open_mfdataset to do step 2 during the import process.

I strongly suspect this will lead to large speed improvements.

Alternatively, you can use this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587633/ways-to-speed-up-open-mfdataset-in-xarray/72455412#72455412)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact issue and posted about it here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9343

Basically, you need to chunk your data in time AND space (you are only chunking by time). This is causing you to load a lot of unnecessary data into memory which is why it's taking so long.

Change this:

```py
data = xr.open_mfdataset(glob_pattern, decode_times=True, chunks={'time': 1000},
                       engine='h5netcdf', data_vars='minimal', coords='minimal', compat='override', parallel=True)
```

To this:

```py
data = xr.open_mfdataset(glob_pattern, decode_times=True, chunks={'time': 1000, 'latitude':1, 'longitude':1},
                       engine='h5netcdf', data_vars='minimal', coords='minimal', compat='override', parallel=True)
```

Now if you were interested in data at multiple points, you'd probably want to use chunks larger than 1 spatial unit but since you are interested in a single point, this should be the fastest.

Hope that helps!